# Web service for sharing DB details

Tags: php, android, web-services, codeigniter, rest

we have already developed a web app using codeigniter and now planning a mobile client(for android phones).The scenario is like this

```
1)mobile client will have a local db same as server db
2)After installing the app an authentication process is there
3)After authentication we need to download the data from server db to mobile client DB.
```

I have created one web service using `REST` api for authentication process and its working but for `step 3` i need help.

Can i use `REST` api for that also or is there exist any other secure mechanism to sync server and mobile client DB ?

Can anyone suggest please!

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

First, you need create a very strong structure compatible with Oauth2, I recommended this library: [Codeigniter RESTserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

After, you must know how works the Oauth2 protocol and implements it.

Read this tutorial, is old but good for your work: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814

Comment: implemented this and is working fine, but is there any mechanism available to synchronise client and server databases.ie if an update occurs on server that must be updated on client as well and viceversa?